# Why am I ALWAYS getting SSL error when contacting Parse.com?

Tags: parse-platform, swift2

Environment: 
Xcode 7.0/Swift 2.0.

I could connect to parse via Xcode 6.4/Swift 1.2; but after switching to Xcode 7.0/Swift 2.0 I've been getting  the following runtime connection error:

> An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made. (Code: 100, Version: 1.7.5)
>
> [Error]: Network connection failed. Making attempt 5 after sleeping
>   for 9.864530 seconds. NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed
>   (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)

I read that it may be due to iOS 9's [security setup](http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/). 
Setting the .plist value 'NSAppTransportSecurity' to turn off this security check didn't change anything.

This problem occurs in simulation or device; every time.

How can I access parse.com as I've always done?

Comment: I had this problem and when you say you added the NSAppTransportSecurity, did you added it like that with the NSApp... as a dictionnary and inside the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads ? See code here <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key> <dict>     <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>     <true/> </dict>

Comment: I've uploaded a snapshot of the piece of my plist covering security.  This didn't change the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I went to [Apple's Security Doc site](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/) to find that I didn't set up my plist correctly.  The following WORKS: this allows me to access parse within iOS9:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add this in your code :

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key> <dict> <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key> <true/> </dict>
```